# Aplicar função a todos os elementos da lista utilizando o VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Existe alguma função/módulo para um objeto do tipo `List` no VB.NET que seja similar ao `array_map()` do PHP?

A ideia é criar uma nova variável com os elementos que satisfaçam a uma determinada condição.

Tenho uma lista de objetos do tipo `FtpListItem`, e preciso apenas dos arquivos em que a data de modificação sejam maiores que a variável `UltimoHorario`. Exemplo de função:

```
Function ValidarArquivo(arquivo As FtpListItem)
    If arquivo.Modified.Compare(UltimoHorario) > 0 Then
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Mostre o que você quer fazer. Provavelmente você pode usar o [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx)

Comment: @bigown o LINQ pode ser utilizado com listas? pensei que funcionava apenas como mapeamento de banco de dados..

Comment: @LúcioRubens Utilize LINQ para isso. Você pode inclusive usar Lambda expressions para simplificar ainda mais a busca. Por exemplo: FtpListItem.Where(i => i.UltimoHorario >0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é uma linguagem de consulta para trabalhar com qualquer tipo de coleção de dados, desde *arrays* até coleções que mapeiam banco de dados.

Você não postou algo que seja fácil identificar o que você quer de fato mas essencialmente deve ser isto:

```
arquivosFiltrados = listaArquivos.Where(x => x.Modified.Compare(UltimoHorario) > 0)
```

Ou se preferir usar sua função:

```
arquivosFiltrados = listaArquivos.Where(x => ValidarArquivo(x))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FilterFile.cs).

Só lembrando que esta lista deve ser do tipo `IEnumarable<FtpListItem>` para funcionar. E sua função precisaria ser modificada para ter um retorno em todos os caminhos possíveis, ou seja, deveria ter um `Return False` se o arquivo individual não atender o critério.

Se tiver outros detalhes eu melhor a resposta. Estou partindo do princípio que sua comparação está sendo feita da forma como deseja.

Procure dar uma boa estudada no LINQ, ele é muito útil para muita coisa, seja na forma apresentada ou na forma de linguagem de consulta conforme a documentação que eu *linkei* acima.